# The Following Setups were Not Matched, WPF MVVM Unit Testing with Moq

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, moq

I am writing a unit test in **WPF** with **Moq** to test whether or not a user clicked the "Yes" button on a `YesNoCancel` MessageBox when they are closing the window.  In my `CloseCommand` I have in my ViewModel gives the following message when the user is closing the window:

```
var result = _messageSvc.Show(
    "Do you want to save changes?",
    "Save Changes", 
    Services.MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel,
    Services.MessageBoxIcon.Question, 
    Services.MessageBoxResult.Yes);
```

My `_messageSvc` is a private instance inside of a custom Messaging service to display messageboxes.  Here is the code for the service:

```
public interface IMessageSvc
{
    void Show(string message);
    MessageBoxResult Show(string message, string caption, MessageBoxButton buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxResult defaultResult = 0);
}

public class MessageSvc : IMessageSvc
{
    public void Show(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }

    public MessageBoxResult Show(string message, string caption, MessageBoxButton buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxResult defaultResult)
    {
        return (MessageBoxResult)MessageBox.Show(message, caption, (System.Windows.MessageBoxButton)buttons, (System.Windows.MessageBoxImage)icon, (System.Windows.MessageBoxResult)defaultResult);
    }
}
```

Note: `MessageBoxButton`, `MessageBoxIcon`, and `MessageBoxResult` are enumerations I made in the same file to mimic what .NET provides out of the box.  I am not showing them here for sake of readability

My unit test is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldAskToSaveOnCloseRespondYesTest()
{
    // Mock and setup initial user data 
    var u= new User
    {
        UserId = 1,
        UserName = "FirstName LastName",
        FavoriteColor = "Blue"
    };
    mainViewModel.UserInfo= new UserInfoDtoWrapper(u);

    // assert the data has not changed yet
    Assert.IsFalse(mainViewModel.UserInfo.IsChanged);

    // change the user data
    mainViewModel.UserInfo.UserName= "LastName FirstName";

    // assert the data has changed
    Assert.IsTrue(mainViewModel.UserInfo.IsChanged);

    // execute window closing
    mainViewModel.CloseCommand.Execute(new object());

    // verify messagebox shows and the 'Yes' button is clicked
    // this will then save the changes made to the user instance
    var messageBox = new Mock<IMessageSvc>();
    messageBox.Setup(x => x.Show(It.Is<string>(y => y == "Do you want to save changes?"),
        It.Is<string>(y => y == "Save Changes"),
        It.Is<MessageBoxButton>(y => y == MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel),
        It.Is<MessageBoxIcon>(y => y == MessageBoxIcon.Question),
        It.Is<MessageBoxResult>(y => y == MessageBoxResult.Yes)))
        .Returns(MessageBoxResult.Yes);

    messageBox.Verify();
}
```

The error comes on the `messageBox.Verify()` line, but from what I can see I am doing it correctly.  I need to get the return value of the messagebox to continue testing what happens after the user clicks the "Yes" button, so I did not want to use `Verify` with a Linq query inside, instead I need to capture the result.

Thanks

Comment: "The error comes on the messageBox.Verify() line" - What error?

Comment: ShouldAskToSaveOnCloseRespondYesTest threw exception: Moq.MockVerificationException: The following setups were not matched: IMessageSvc x=> x.Show(It.Is<String>(y => y == "Do you want to save changes?"), It.Is<String>(y => y == "Save Changes") . . .

Comment: Where's the rest of the code between Setup and Verify? Currently no test is performed.

Comment: I guess that's where my question is.  I need to verify the messagebox is shown.  Should I then just call "MessageBox.Show" or show the messageBox object I created above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work. You have 2 issues in your test code:

1. You first fire the `CloseCommand` (which is assumed to call the `IMessageSvc.Show` method), and only then setup a mock for that service.
2. You setup a new mock for a service but don't use it.

To correct these errors:

- Change the order such that it is a correct 'arrange' - 'act' - 'assert' order
- Inject your mocked service in the view model using dependency injection

Here is an example:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly IMessageSvc _messageSvc;

    public MainViewModel(IMessageSvc svc)
    {
        this._messageSvc = svc;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void ShouldAskToSaveOnCloseRespondYesTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var messageBox = new Mock<IMessageSvc>();
    messageBox.Setup(x => x.Show(It.Is<string>(y => y == "Do you want to save changes?"),
        It.Is<string>(y => y == "Save Changes"),
        It.Is<MessageBoxButton>(y => y == MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel),
        It.Is<MessageBoxIcon>(y => y == MessageBoxIcon.Question),
        It.Is<MessageBoxResult>(y => y == MessageBoxResult.Yes)))
        .Returns(MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        .Verifiable();

    var mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(messageBox.Object);

    // Act
    mainViewModel.CloseCommand.Execute(new object());

    // Assert
    messageBox.Verify();
}
```

Comment: I am adding the message service object to the view model constructor on the unit test class initialization so it is being injected from there.  Within the unit test method however, after arranging my code to how you showed I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @J-man, no, you haven't arranged your code as I suggested. You're creating a new mock for your service in your test method. Exactly this mocked service has to be provided to the view model. You have to either create your view model in the test method (as I proposed) or setup your service mock in the class initialization where the view model is created.

Comment: You are correct @dymanoid, I mistakenly was setting up a new mocked instance of my messaging service, when I already has access to the class scoped messageSvc object which is injected in the initialize method of the unit test class.  So I should have been setting up the `messageSvc.Setup(...)` instead of what I was doing `var messageBox = new Mock<IMessageSvc>(); messageBox.Setup(...)`.  No wonder it could not find the correct setup, you are correct in that the SAME object needs to be injected into the VM, I was mistakenly trying to inject a new one.  Thanks!!  I'll mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are setting up your mocked method *after* testing the code that would call it. Re-arrange your test into the [AAA (Arrange, Act, Assert)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694602.aspx) pattern like so:

```
var messageBox = new Mock<IMessageSvc>();
messageBox.Setup(x => x.Show(It.Is<string>(y => y == "Do you want to save changes?"),
    It.Is<string>(y => y == "Save Changes"),
    It.Is<MessageBoxButton>(y => y == MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel),
    It.Is<MessageBoxIcon>(y => y == MessageBoxIcon.Question),
    It.Is<MessageBoxResult>(y => y == MessageBoxResult.Yes)))
    .Returns(MessageBoxResult.Yes);

mainViewModel.CloseCommand.Execute(new object());

messageBox.Verify(x => x.Show(It.Is<string>(y => y == "Do you want to save changes?"),
    It.Is<string>(y => y == "Save Changes"),
    It.Is<MessageBoxButton>(y => y == MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel),
    It.Is<MessageBoxIcon>(y => y == MessageBoxIcon.Question),
    It.Is<MessageBoxResult>(y => y == MessageBoxResult.Yes)));
```

Comment: I tried this before, error that is being returned in this situation is `Expected Invocation on the Mock once, but was 0 times` with `messageBox.Verify(x => x.Show(
                It.Is<string>(y => y == "Do you want to save changes?"),
                It.Is<string>(y => y == "Save Changes"),
                It.Is<MessageBoxButton>(y => y == MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel),
                It.Is<MessageBoxIcon>(y => y == MessageBoxIcon.Question),
                It.Is<MessageBoxResult>(y => y == MessageBoxResult.Yes)), Times.Once);`

Comment: I have my IMessageService injected into the ViewModel and initialized in the Unit Test class, so when I run `_messageSvc.Verify(x =>
            x.Show(It.Is<string>(y => y == "Do you want to save changes?"),
            It.Is<string>(y => y == "Save Changes"),
            It.Is<MessageBoxButton>(y => y == MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel),
            It.Is<MessageBoxIcon>(y => y == MessageBoxIcon.Question),
            It.Is<MessageBoxResult>(y => y == MessageBoxResult.Yes)), Times.Once);` it works, but I need to setup the messagebox to get the return value